# Assign Infinity value to a variable

Tags: c, autosar

Hi I want to assign Infinity value to a variable in my autostart code, I am going to use `math.h` but it gives qac warning identifier is not declared

I have included `math.h` header file still qac gives me a warning identifier has not been declared. Is there any way to assign ?

```
# include <math.h>
int Calcula(x_val ,y_val)
{ 
 if(x_val >y_val )
  return INFINITY
}

// this code is not exact code ..
```

it should return INFINITY ,

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/INFINITY

Comment: Your function returns only a value in a specific case and returns nothing otherwise. `INFINITY` can't be hold by an `int` variable, it is a implementation defined constant of type `float`.

Comment: `int` does not have any infinity. It can only hold a very finite values.

Answer (score 2):

From this [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isinf), INFINITY is a macro which expands to a type float.

> If the implementation supports floating-point infinities, the macro
>   INFINITY expands to constant expression of type float which evaluates
>   to positive or unsigned infinity.

Thus, your code should be modified as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float Calcula(float x_val, float y_val)
{
    if( x_val > y_val ) {return INFINITY; }
    else { /* your else if you have one */ }
}

int main()
{   
    float a=4.0, b=2.0;
    float ret;
    ret = isinf(Calcula(a, b));
    printf("Return value is %f", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

This should print 1.